# Trackpad scroll goes nuts

Tags: 15.04, touchpad, scrolling

I've had Ubuntu of my laptop for about a week, and although the two-fingered scroll on my trackpad usually works fine, every now and then some widget flips out and thinks I'm scrolling when I just want to move the pointer. The font size selector in gnome-terminal's preferences does this. Just by moving the mouse, it jumped to 3.722e+05 pt.

EDIT: I haven't experienced this in quite some time. If you're looking for a solution, sorry, I won't be able to help.

Comment: I have this too